# Best C++ API for using Maps(HashMap), Strings, and date

Tags: c++, string, datetime, hashmap

What are the C++ APIs(commericial, and Non-Commercial) that provide the easy ways for the following requisites:

1) The table data structure which is simillar to Maps in java (Single key and Single value) and also for multiple keys for single value.

2) Conversion of different data types to STRING values (I mean integer 10 to string from "10")

3) Which provide information about the current date and time and also should be helpful by allowing airthemetic operations on dates and capable of extracting retrieving months, days, years, seconds and milliseconds if possible.

Comment: If I were you, I'd begin by familiarizing myself with the standard C++ library, and then with Boost. You'll find most of what you need there.

Comment: How about `std::unordered_map` and `std::stringstream` for the first and third?

Comment: As suggested in the boost libraries, lexical_cast would handle a lot of the second. It also has the date/time library that should handle the third as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about the standard library as defined in the C++ standard?

1)

```
#include <map> // std::map, key-value pairs, unique keys
               // also contains std::multimap, same as std::map, duplicate keys
// C++11 only:
#include <unordered_map> // std::unordered_map, key-value pairs, unique keys, hash table
                         // also contains std::unordered_multimap
```

2)

```
#include <sstream> // std::(i|o)stringstream, allow conversion from / to different data types

// C++11 only:
#include <string>  // std::to_string for arithmetic types to strings (int, double, etc)
                   // std::stoi, std::stol, etc for strings to arithmetic types
// Boost library
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp> // boost::lexical_cast for conversions similar to stringstreams
```

3)

```
// C standard library, part of C++ standard library
#include <ctime> // std::time, std::gmtime, std::localtime
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the Info..I will start experiment with the information you have given..Thanks a lot again..

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to use [boost](http://www.boost.org)

1. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html
2. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm
3. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: I don't think you need boost for the first two, though boost is a lot faster than stringstream for #2.  #1 can be handled with a `std::map<key, std::shared_ptr<value>>`.

Comment: And for #2 I think you meant to link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html,which is quite different